# ATI Stream SDK on ubuntu 9.04

Tags: parallel-processing, gpgpu, gpu

I have used ATI Stream SDK on windows XP SP3 and implemented one algorithm on GPU. But Now I am interested in scaling this algorithm on multiple GPUs on mutiple machines I switched to UBUNTU to use MPI ( To send messages ).

I googled this but I got references for installation on SLES and RHEL but I am looking for UBUNTU 9.04.

Thanks 
GG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD is switching to OpenCL based API soon. May be it will be worthwhile holding your horses till the OpenCL API stabilizes. Cuda is far ahead of the curve in terms of GPU usability, there is a nice project called MAGMA which is bringing together the LAPACK library for joint CPU-GPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

I know of people who are using the ATI Stream SDK and ACML-GPU on Ubuntu without any special problems -- that is, no problems that they wouldn't have on any other Linux distro.

If you can get the Catalyst drivers installed correctly (which in this case will probably mean compiling your kernel modules) and your X windows configured correctly (especially DRI module, and there are security issues if you want Stream to work with remote access) it should work.

I'm tempted to ask/comment how you plan to share GPUs between multiple MPI processes, but that's probably wandering off-topic.